# MVC Is there a way to make sure a specific ViewModel property doesn't get passed in a Html.BeginForm(action, controller, ModelData)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

**ANSWERED**

*See answers section below*

I've been struggling for hours with this problem and I haven't found anything that relates, so apologies if this post is a duplicate.

I'll start by constructing a problem related to my own.

Let's say we create a ViewModel:

```
public class XmlViewModel(){

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public string XML { get; set; }
}
```

and a constructor method which loads the View and as well as another that gets called when the submit is registered on the View.

```
public class Extractor{

public ActionResult Index()
{
    XmlViewModel xmlVM = new XmlViewModel ()
    {
        XML = "Sample XML";  
    };

    return View(xmlVM);
}

public ActionResult GetXml(XmlViewModel xmlVM){

    
    xmlVM.XML = GetXMLByCode();

    return View ("Index", xmlVM)
    
}
}
```

Then the view **Index** as below

```
@model Project.ViewModel.XmlViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetXml", "Extractor", Model))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.XML, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <pre id="XML">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.XML))</pre>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Generate XML" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

So in this scenario I'm starting the page with:

[image]

When the user clicks Submit using a XML Code, I want the Code to be run against some collection of XML, then that returned XML replaces the "SampleXML"

Problem is when the form gets submitted again(Twice) (Now with the XML field holding a few hundred characters) it overloads the Query and returns this:

[image]

Because yep you guessed it, the XML fills up the Request with the XML from the previous Form result.

So my question is, is there any way to clear the ViewModel Property so it isn't passed in the Query, or some attribute to add that will tell the ViewModel to not pass the property through the Html.BeginForm()?

If possible I would like to stay away from passing the ViewModel properties individually as the actual problem's ViewModel is more complicated and it would be troublesome going down that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWERED**

I eventually figured it out by doing the following in the view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    ViewBag.XML= XmlViewModel.XML;
    XmlViewModel.XML = "";
}

---

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.XML, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <pre id="XML">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(ViewBag.XML))</pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when the view is loaded, the Viewbag will hold the XML being returned and I can safely empty the model data before returning it to the Html.BeginForm()

Keeping for anyone in the same situation

Answer (score 0):

After my suggestions, if you are still getting header to large, I can help diagnose.

Add an xml file to your project.  Add tons of xml to it.  Right click to get properties.  For build action, change to embedded resource.

[image: your file you added]

Where I have WebApplication2.XMLFile1.xml, you should have your assembly name dot then your file name.  You can right click on your project, and see properties to get assembly name.

Here is my code

```
namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class XmlViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string XML { get; set; }
    }
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public static string GetXMLByCode()
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            var resourceName = "WebApplication2.XMLFile1.xml";

            string result = String.Empty;
            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return result;
        }

        public ActionResult GetXml(XmlViewModel xmlVM)
        {
            xmlVM.XML = GetXMLByCode();
            return View("Index9", xmlVM);
        }

        public ActionResult Index9()
        {
            XmlViewModel xmlVM = new XmlViewModel { XML = "Sample XML" };
            return View(xmlVM);
        }
```

here is my view

```
@model WebApplication2.Controllers.XmlViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index9";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("GetXml", "Home", Model))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Code, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Code, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.XML, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <pre id="XML">@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(Model.XML))</pre>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Generate XML" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, correct me if I'm wrong but the only difference here is the source for the XML getting returned by the GetXML..No actual changes have been made to how the view manages the Model. Am I perhaps not seeing it?